# export public key from keychain access

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to archive my app for distribution on two computers. I exported the private key successfully and imported it to my second machine, however run into errors when imported the public key.

Everywhere I search people always mention only exporting of the private key - why is that? how can I export the public key and transfer it successfully? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you export you *private* key, you should get a .p12 file. Import that file on the other machine. It should have everything in it you need. You don't need to specifically export and import the *public* key.

Comment: but how do i generate one on the second machine?

Comment: this was the answer for me, just export the private key (the nested key icon). Once you get the key you can email it to yourself then open the email on the second machine, download to downloads folder > open keychain > system > +(plus) button > then import from there

Answer (score 51):

It's been broken since 2009 as reflected in [this bug report](http://www.openradar.me/7092640).

In case that report wanders off the internet, here's the relevant instructions to import a public key pem file.  You'll want to execute this in Terminal.

```
security import pub_key.pem -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Comment: Thanks! Spent 2 days breaking my head against the monitor

Comment: It really helps me a lot!

Comment: Will this work for Private Key too of a remote server?

Comment: it says `1 key imported`, but why doesn't it show in Keychain Access?

Comment: Hi, trying to do this but returns `security: Error reading infile pub_key.pem: No such file or directory` ...I have an SSH (.pem) keypair for an AWS instance...do I need to import to keychain?

Comment: FYI, in keychain the imported file will show up with the name "Imported Public Key"

Comment: I also facing this issue `security: Error reading infile pub_key.pem: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Same as DougW,

But first you must directing your terminal to directory of the key

Then change the pub_key to the name of key you will import

Example:

your key on **folder Documents** , and the key name is **my_login.pem**

So, you must write in terminal

```
$ cd Documents

$ security import my_login.pem -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

But be careful, you must need a backslash if you key name like

```
$ security import \<my_login.pem\> -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Backslash for **escape character** as text

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1976408

[Don't understand the backslash here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681001/dont-understand-the-backslash-here)

**For Your Information**

And you can import keychains with change the directory, the directory show in here

[keychains directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie1nr.png)

just let your pointer on the kind of keychain you want to know

So it will be like this

```
security import **yourkeyname** -k ~/Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

**BE CAREFUL** with this

**You must know what you do**