# create maven project from command line

Tags: maven, command-line, pom.xml, project-setup

I am trying to follow this tutorial http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/

It seems ok but when it told me to do write the following lines of code I had some issues

the code:

> mvn archetype:generate \
>    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
>    -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
>    -DartifactId=my-app

Firstly, is that meant to be one command or is it a series with returns in between each line? 
Or is it the name of a list of subdirectories?

Also when I typed it all out and executed it as one command it said there was no pom.xml, but of course there is no pom.xml because the project has not been created and according to the tutorial it should create it for you. So why is mine not?

Maven is really beginning to tie me in knots now

Comment: remove the \ and it's a single line

Answer (score 2):

Backslash means the command continues to the next line (if you have a newline character). https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681059

You can simple enter `mvn archetype:generate` in terminal and you will be asked to enter groupId, artifactId etc. See please [example](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html).