# Transferring public and private key on mac

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain, private-key, public-key

How do I transfer both private / public keys from one mac to the other?

I know how to export the private key to .p12 with Keychain Access, and then when I double click it in the destination mac, it's added to Keychain Access.
However, when I export the public key to .pem file, double clicking it in the destination mac just spits out:

`An error has occurred. Unable to import an item. The contents of this item cannot be retrieved.`

When I tried [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874164/export-public-key-from-keychain-access) of `security import pub.pem -k login.keychain`, it said `1 key imported.`, but it doesn't show on Keychain Access.

- Am I missing anything?
- Should I not bother with transferring the public key?
- Is importing just that private key enough?
- Is the only way just [recovering the public key from the private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847081/i-lost-my-public-key-can-i-recover-it-from-a-private-key)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/704692/cant-import-public-key-into-osx-keychain), it looks like when running the `security import...` command, it's added to the keychain with the generic name `Imported Public Key`.

Now you just need to rename it to the relevant one (e.g. like the private key name).